# How do I add 2 arrays together and get the average of the sum?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, average

i'm trying to add 2 arrays together and get the average of the sum
how do i do this? i want to produce the answers in a array aswell.

```
public static void part1 (){

    double examMarks [] = {50,40,60,80,70,11};
    double courseworkmarks [] = {65,49,58,77,35,40};

    System.out.println ("These are the exam marks and the course work marks");//First row is the exam marks, second row is the course work marks
    computeMarks (examMarks);
    computeMarks1 (courseworkmarks);

}
public static void computeMarks(double[] examMarks)
{
    for (int row=0;row<examMarks.length;row++){
            System.out.print (examMarks[row] +"\t");
        }
    System.out.println();
    }
public static void computeMarks1(double[] courseworkmarks)
{
    for (int row=0;row<courseworkmarks.length;row++){
            System.out.print (courseworkmarks[row] +"\t");
        }
    System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: im trying to add examMarks and courseworkmarks. note that i need to add the first column and then get the average and second column and then get the average. so 50+65, 40+49, 60+58 etc.

Comment: What's wrong with your solution right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like following

```
    double examMarks [] = {50,40,60,80,70,11};
    double courseworkmarks [] = {65,49,58,77,35,40};

    double avgMarks[] =new double[examMarks.length];

    for(int i=0;i<avgMarks.length;i++){
        avgMarks[i]=(examMarks[i]+courseworkmarks[i])/2;
    }
```

Comment: Note: this is fine unless the arrays are 2 different lengths. Probably fine for this situation, but a good practice should be to make sure array lengths won't cause an ArrayOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @RUJordan - If the arrays are different lengths, then OP's goal would make no sense. It's only defined for arrays that are equal length.

Comment: "Probably fine for this situation"

Answer (score 0):

Have your method return an array. You can do something like this

```
public static double[] computeMarks(double[] examMarks)
{
    int[] newArray = new int[examMarks.length];

    for (int row=0;row<examMarks.length;row++){
        newArray[i] = (examMarks[row] + courseworkmarks[row])  / 2;
    }

    return newArray

}
```

To print

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    double[] array = computeMarks(yourArray);

    for (int i  = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        System.out.println(array[i] + "\t");
    }
}
```

Comment: i believe that this is what do you mean (examMarks[row]+courseworkmarks[row]) / 2;

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I was just giving more an example for returning an array, as per OP request.  But for a final solution to problem, OP may want that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a array with the length = array.length + array2.length;

And use **System.arraycopy** to copy the values.

Below is a sample method for combining the 2 arrays.

```
public double[] copyTwoArrays(double[] arrayOne, double[] arrayTwo)
{
    if(null == arrayOne || arrayOne.length == 0)
    {
        return arrayTwo;
    }

    if( null == arrayTwo || arrayTwo.length == 0)
    {
        return arrayOne;
    }       
    double[] result = new double[arrayOne.length + arrayTwo.length];

    System.arraycopy(arrayOne, 0, result, 0, arrayOne.length);
    System.arraycopy(arrayTwo, 0, result, arrayOne.length, arrayTwo.length);

    return result;
}
```

Take your arrays for example:

```
double examMarks [] = {50,40,60,80,70,11};
double courseworkmarks [] = {65,49,58,77,35,40};
```

You can use the following code to populate the combined array.

```
double[] result = someInstance.copyTwoArrays(examMarks, courseworkmarks);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like

```
 public static void totalMarks(double[] examMarks, double[] courseworkmarks){
      double total[] = new double[6];
      double totalMarks = 0;

      System.out.println("================================================");
      for(int i = 0;i < examMarks.length;i++){
      total[i]=examMarks[i] + courseworkmarks[i];
      totalMarks = totalMarks+total[i];
          System.out.print(total[i]+"\t");
      }
      System.out.println("========================================");
      System.out.println("total marks are "+totalMarks);
      System.out.println("average is "+(totalMarks/examMarks.length));
     // total;
  }
```

If you need you can break it into two parts for total and for average